# Помогите решить проблему исчезновения окна в crm при клике на календарь

Tags: javascript

Я делаю crm в ней есть задачи, где указывается дата с помощью календаря **datetimepicker** отличный календарик, но есть беда! У меня в системе все формы для добавления задач, сделок, клиентов подгружаются внутрь небольшого html кода модального окна.

Проблема такая:

Если добавлять сразу только задачу, проблем нет, т.е. жмешь **добавить задачу**, нажимаешь на поле дата выскакивает календарик тыкаешь нужную дату и все в порядке.

Если перед тем как добавить задачу, открыл какую-то другую форму, то при открытии добавить задачу возникает баг, при клике на поле дата выскакивает календарик, тыкаешь на дату, окно сворачивается, дико бесит клиентов!

Братцы помогите никак не могу решить эту проблему =(

Вот гифка ярко все показывающая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему у Вас datetimepicker'ы в DOM находятся вне самой всплывающей формы? Вам не кажется, что логично оставлять элементы управления там, где они должны быть, а не заставлять их валяться где попало в дереве DOM? Есть подозрение, что из-за этого клик по календарю уходит не в модальное окно, а за его пределы вызывая такое поведение.

Comment: @AlexKrass, мне вот как раз и кажется что именно из-за этого, но я никак не могу понять как именно то что вы говорите сделать... уже мучаюсь неделю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, как и сказал @AlexKrass, заключается в том, что **datepicker** в дереве **DOM** находится вне модального окна.
Поэтому ваш код, который должен отрабатывать при клике вне модального окна, отрабатывает и на клик по **datepicker**.

У вас 3 способа решить эту проблему:

1. Перенести тело **datepicker** в нужное место в **DOM**
2. Перед тем как закрывать модальное окно, проверять не кликнули-ли по **datepicker** и если клик был по нему, то не закрывать модальное окно.
3. Начать использовать **[events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)**

Comment: решил проблему, просто добавил один параметр который указывает куда добавлять элементы календаря и все.